# Changing Epicor ERP10 standard system code

Tags: epicorerp

How can I change Epicor ERP10 standard system code for Purchase Requisition Entry in the Line pane? I would like to change the Due Date from displaying current date to blank everytime making a new line. Please help me.

Comment: You can add a BPM to do this. Add a post processing directive that sets the OrderDate field to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Method Directives.

Here's how to add one.

1. Find and open Method Directives Maintenance (System Management/Business Process Management/Method Directives Maintenance)
2. Click on `Method Code`, select your business object (`Req` in your case).
3. Click on  `Search` and select the appropriate method from there (since it is an Add Line event that you want to work with, it should look something like `GetNew...Detail`). Click OK.
4. Go to `Post Processing` tab and hit `New` on the toolbar.
5. Give this directive a name you like and click on `Design`.
6. Here, in the BPM Workflow Designer, scroll to the bottom of the panel on the left and drag the `Set Field` icon to the right from the `Setters` section.
7. Now when this `Set Field...` icon is selected, it should show you a table with a column called `Action`. The next part should be intuitive in itself, but I have gone through the steps and written it here anyways.
8. Select `DueDate` field of the `ReqDetail` table (under `specified` field section). Set it to `null` for `the new row` here.
9. Save and Exit.

This should do the job, or if it doesn't do exactly what you want. There's always more options in the Method Directives Maintenance section that you can fiddle around with. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 

Comment: @Kieym: Did that work? Accept the answer if it did. :-)

Comment: Yes it did, sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for your kind assistance 